# Какой тайм-трекер посоветуете?

Tags: поиск-программ

Прочел ряд "похожих" вопросов из списка и вроде как свой не нашёл. Ребят, посоветуйте пожалуйста тайм трекер для работы с отслеживанием программ в которых я сижу.
Из главного:

1. Я сам включаю и выключаю его (начало/окончание работы)
2. Во время работы он отслеживает в каких приложениях и на каких сайтах я гуляю
3. Статистика собирается в админку где можно посмотреть что я делал и когда
4. Скриншоты экрана не обязательны

Я раньше использовал [Tmetric](https://tmetric.com/), но к сожалению теперь он не работает. Видимо ушли с РФ.
Кто знает похожий не нагруженный лишним функционалом трекер и если не беслпатно, то хотя-бы за 5-10$ в месяц.